# Groovy not in collection

Tags: groovy

The idiomatic way to check if a list contains something in Groovy is to use `in`.

```
if ('b' in ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

But how do you nicely check if something is not in a collection?

```
if (!('g' in ['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

Using logical not seems messy and the `!` is hidden to the casual glance. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this in Groovy?

Thanks!

Comment: In another language, I've taken to using `false ==` instead of `!` for my negation needs.  Not quite as clean as what you're looking for here, but it's definitely harder to miss.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, and for people reaching this thread post-2020, Groovy 3.0.0 [introduced](https://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html) the `!in` operator.

As per the OP example, it would be used like that:

```
if ('g' !in ['a','b','c'])
```

Comment: Note: negation of `in` is not supported in some versions of groovy

Answer (score 47):

Another way to write it is with `contains`, e.g.

```
if (!['a', 'b', 'c'].contains('b'))
```

It saves the extra level of parentheses at the cost of replacing the operator with a method call.

Comment: Still puts the `not` far away from the `contains`, making it easy to miss at a glance :/

Answer (score 35):

I think there is no `not in` pretty syntax, unfortunately. But you can use a helper variable to make it more readable:

```
def isMagicChar = ch in ['a', 'b', 'c']
if (!isMagicChar) ...
```

Or, in this case, you may use a regex :)

```
if (ch !=~ /[abc]/) ...
```

Answer (score 14):

You can add new functions:

```
Object.metaClass.notIn = { Object collection ->
    !(delegate in collection)
}


assert "2".notIn(['1', '2q', '3'])
assert !"2".notIn(['1', '2', '3'])

assert 2.notIn([1, 3])
assert !2.notIn([1, 2, 3])

assert 2.notIn([1: 'a', 3: 'b'])
assert !2.notIn([1: 'a', 2: 'b'])
```

Answer (score 9):

More readable, I'm not sure:

```
assert ['a','b','c'].any{it == 'b'}
assert ['a','b','c'].every{it != 'g'}
```

For your example:

```
if (['a','b','c'].every{it != 'g'})
```

---

A few months ago, I suggested a [new operator overloading ! (**not** operator)](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/New-operator-overloading-not-operator-td4768200.html). Now, maybe you can use any odd number of exclamations ;)

```
if(!!!('g' in ['a','b','c']))
```

Comment: At your link, the Codehaus Groovy project manager said "You can always use some expando metaclass trick, or an AST transformation, to add those isNot methods". Now, if only he'd written "I will use some expando metaclass trick, or an AST transformation, to add those isNot methods in the next release of Codehaus Groovy". Then we wouldn't have a problem would we.

Comment: if(!!!('g' in ['a','b','c'])) -- read as "if g is really really really not in this list"

Answer (score 1):

According to Grails documentation about creating criteria [here](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), you can use something like this:

```
not {'in'("age",[18..65])}
```

In this example, you have a property named `"age"` and you want to get rows that are NOT between 18 and 65. Of course, the `[18..65]` part can be substituted with any list of values or range you need.

Comment: True, but my question was not specifically about a criteria (which is constructing a sql query.)   I wanted to know if the groovy language and libraries generally support something more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding one of the original answers:

```
if (!['a', 'b', 'c'].contains('b'))
```

Somebody mentioned that it is easy to miss the ! because it's far from the method call. This can be solved by assigning the boolean result to a variable and just negate the variable.

```
def present = ['a', 'b', 'c'].contains('b')
if (!present) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **contains(string)** method is nice and simple to read if something is contained or not contained in the list to be checked against. Take a look the **example below** for more insight.

**EXAMPLE**

```
//Any data you are looking to filter  
List someData = ['a', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'o', 'o']

//A filter/conditions to not match or match against
List myFilter = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 

//Some variables for this example
String filtered, unfiltered 

//Loop the data and filter for not contains or contains
someData.each {
   if (!myFilter.contains(it)){
      unfiltered += it
   } else {        
      filtered += it
   }
}

assert unfiltered = "foo"
assert filtered = "abc"
```

**CONTAINS( )**

**Parameters: text** - *a String to look for.*

**Returns: true** *if this string contains the given text*

[source](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

What about `disjoint` ?

```
def elements = [1, 2, 3]
def element = 4
assert elements.disjoint([element])
element = 1
assert !elements.disjoint([element])
```

Bonus : it stops iterating when an element match