# How to remove a dependency from the pom when publishing in mavenCentral

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to publish a library in MavenCentral. So I'm following this [Chris Banes post](http://zserge.com/blog/gradle-maven-publish.html).

Everything works but I have a little problem: The library uses the google play services lib:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
```

But I don't need the dependency, it is just optional and, if the developer using my app also adds the play services to his dependencies, I want to detect it and use some classes. But it the developer doesn't add this dependency, I detect the classes are missing and I don't use them.

So basically I want to use the dependency in order to the build to compile, but I dont want the POM file to add this dependency. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Maven plugin doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html), you can use `pom.whenConfigured` to reorganize dependencies.

For instance, the following will not take `junit` & `play-services` artifactId as dependencies :

```
whenConfigured {
    p - >
        p.dependencies = p.dependencies.findAll {
            dep - > (dep.artifactId.notIn(["junit", "play-services"]))
        }
}
```

In your example you will have the following to exclude `play-services` :

```
pom {

    project {
        name POM_NAME
        packaging POM_PACKAGING
        description POM_DESCRIPTION
        url POM_URL

        scm {
            url POM_SCM_URL
            connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
            developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
        }

        licenses {
            license {
                name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                url POM_LICENCE_URL
                distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
            }
        }

        developers {
            developer {
                id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
            }
        }
    }

    whenConfigured {
        p - >
            p.dependencies = p.dependencies.findAll {
                dep - > (dep.artifactId.notIn(["play-services"]))
            }
    }
}

//https://stackoverflow.com/a/26810828/2614364
Object.metaClass.notIn = { Object collection ->
    !(delegate in collection)
}
```

You can also exclude as `dep.groupId` or `dep.version`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I'm not very experienced with gradle nor groovy, in the Chris Banes example where do I put this code? If I try to put it in the maven-push.gradle file it complains in the format

Comment: Does it work if you replace `pom.project` from your `build.gradle` with the `pom` object in my post ?

Comment: Okey, I have it working, basically added this line `pom.whenConfigured { pom ->
                    pom.dependencies=[]
                }` inside the `mavenDeployer{}` to avoid publishing the dependencies of my project. Thanks so much

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I used this to remove unit testing lib dependencies from MavenCentral pom